# can I send serialized data along with other variables through JQuery $.post?

Tags: jquery, ajax

so lets say I wanted to essentially do this:

```
$.post(
    'search_item.php', 
    { 
        serialzed_data, 
        save: form.save.value, 
        is_correct: form.is_correct.value , 
        etc...
    }
)
```

What is the correct syntax to do so?

many thanks,

**EDIT** to specify:

lets say I have this:

```
$.post(
    'search_item.php', 
    { 
        'checks':post_data, 
        'option[]':option, 
        save: form.save.value, 
        item: form.item.value, 
        name: form.i_name.value, 
        desc: form.i_desc.value, 
        text: form.i_text.value 
    },
    function(output)    {
        $('#return2').html(output).show();
    });
```

now with that current .post I want to add this to it and post them together:

```
var serialized_data = $('input[name^="checks"]:checked').serialize();
```

can I do it?

**EDIT** latest attempt:

```
var post_data = $('input[name^="checks"]:checked').serialize();

        var data = $.extend({}, post_data, {
        'option[]':option, save: form.save.value, 
        item: form.item.value, 
        name: form.i_name.value, 
        desc: form.i_desc.value, 
        text: form.i_text.value
        });

        $.post('search_item.php', data ,
        function(output)    {
            $('#return2').html(output).show();
        });
```

Comment: Define "serialized  data". Objects in javascript ought to have name for each their property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) instead (`.serialize` turns the elements into a string, not an array) like so:

```
$.post('search_item.php', {
        serializedData: $('input[name^="checks"]:checked').serializeArray(),
        extraVar: value
    },
    function(output)    {
        $('#return2').html(output).show();
    });
```

The `serializedData` will be an array, not a 'dictionary', so you'll have to parse it out on the other end.

Actually... `.serialize` would work just fine too. If you're using PHP on the backend, you'd just have to pass it through [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

or you can make an actual object of key/value pairs and go with Phil's solution [using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery).

Comment: either! depends on your backend. I'd probably use `.serialize` because it's super easy to parse into a dictionary in most languages.

Comment: my serialized data is not coming through on the other side :S

Comment: then your problem is elsewhere. start simpler. try passing `{var:"val"}` or something and see if you can access that from your script. use firebug or chrome developer tools to check the request and response.

Comment: got my serialized data posting now, gna try that parse_str coz serializeArray() didnt seem to work.

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and show us what you've got if you're still having trouble.

Comment: thankkkk **** for that. its not even funny how long I am been trying to do that. thank you @Mark and @Phil.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `serialzed_data` is an object of key -> value properties, use [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), eg

```
var data = $.extend({}, serialzed_data, {
    save: form.save.value,
    is_correct: form.is_correct.value,
    // etc
});

$.post('search_item.php', data, ...
```

Comment: hmmm not having any luck. :( i've edited with my latest attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
data: {
    'formData'         : $("#someForm").serialize(),
    'anotherParameter' : 'someOtherData',
     and so on .... 
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried cakar's method and it works beautifully. Use parse_str() in the php file to get the serialized data which is passed from jquery into an array